# Makefile Tools doesn't work for some reason

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

I want to use the make command to compile my files. I installed Makefile Tools from the Marketplace, created a Makefile in my directory, but when I use the make command, it throws an error:

> make : Имя "make" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла
> сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания
> имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего п овторите
> попытку. строка:1 знак:1
>
> - make main.cpp
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (make:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

which means that make was not found. I didn't touch any configuration files. I searched the Net and found nothing about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's helpful to us if the question provides more details about your environment: what is "Makefile Tools"?  Which "Marketplace"?  What operating system are you using?  Also, when formatting command output in your question please use the "Code Sample" format, not the "Blockquote" format, so that SO doesn't reformat the text.

If you mean the Visual Code extension "Makefile Tools", then that extension only provides an interface to running `make` and managing Makefiles; it doesn't provide the actual `make` program itself.

If you're using a Windows system you will have to go find a `make` program and install it on your system before you can run it.  There are various options depending on what environment you want to build in.